# reload/replace image jquery as a list item in <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, replace

hi all i am appending images inside as a list item in unordered list html 
and using jquery for inserting item in unordered list dynamically using below code

```
 for(var i=1; i<=5; i++){       
   $('ul').append('<li class="stage1">'+ stage1img[i]+'</li>')
 }
```

ths image will be loaded on page load 
now on button click i want to relace all images  .i.e all list item(li)with other items as below
 i have tried

```
for(var j=6; j<=10;j++){
      $('li.stage1').replaceWith('<li>'+ stage1img[j]+ '</li>');
     }
```

Comment: i think you have a typo in the second example... ´ stage1img[j]+'>´

Comment: You have syntax error in replace with function.Missing single cot before li  replaceWith('<li>'+ stage1img[j]+'</li>');

Comment: If you have replace content of li then does not require li tag in replacewith function.You can directly write your replace text in function.see example in my below answer

Answer (score 1):

I think where you're going wrong is in your jQuery selection. Try adding `.eq()`

```
for(var j=6; j<=10;j++){
  $('li.stage1').eq(j-6).replaceWith('<li>'+ stage1img[j]+'stage1 </li>');
 }
```

Comment: -6 because your for loop starts at 6. `.eq()` would need to start at 0 in this instance.

Comment: and this image is used into gallery which is load on page load by defaulf image as above code in my question and i m replacing it on button click

Comment: I can't understand why this do not solved the problem. Is it helpful to replacing the images by identify them through src attr like so:  `$('li.stage1:has(img[src="'+$(stage1img[j-5]).attr('src')+'"])').replaceWith('<li>'+ stage1img[j]+ '</li>');` ?

Comment: @sofl thnx but even this is not loading the image

Answer (score 1):

I have modify your code please try it.

```
for(var j=6; j<=10;j++){
      $('li.stage1').replaceWith(stage1img[j]);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all the

items ..y dont you change HTML of container?

```
var strHTML='';
for(var j=6; j<=10;j++){
     strHTML +='<li>'+ stage1img[j]+ </li>';
     }

//then consider <div> is the container of all this <li> simply do:
$('div').html(strHTML);
```

Comment: Please correct your syntax error strHTML +='<li>'+ stage1img[j]+ '</li>';

Comment: @lenda: you must b having some other container for all list items. you can use that

Comment: @Harry: this is technical forum.. and such syntax must not b the reason for commenting

Comment: If user directly copy/paste your code and use it then he will get error that's why i am pointing you.

Comment: such errors can be corrected..they are not complex type.now lets stop arguing on silly things.

Comment: ok but i have already done and ther is not syntax error and array contains image tag inside as a value thatis perfectly fine working

Comment: ok all this is my mistake i should type properly now let concentrate on question

Answer (score 1):

I am not very well versed in Javascript, but if you want to ol then, why not you first remove old ol and then add new ol. to remove ol use something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(document).ready(function() {
  // when the tag with id="btn" is clicked
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    // removes all LI with class="cls" in OL
    $('ol li.cls').remove();
  });
});
--></script>
```

and then append new items as you were doing previously.